# How to use a non abstract method from a Abstract class in another class without extending

Tags: java

How to use a non-abstract method from an `abstract` class in another class **without extending**?

Comment: Simple. You can't.

Comment: Static could do it

Comment: Show “another class” and the method declaration

Comment: Clearly your abstract class is violating the single responsibility principle.

Comment: Get yourself some good tutorial on Java and work through it. Completely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't.

To call any non-static method of some class `A`, you need an instance of `A` or of a subclass of `A`, as such a method typically operates on data within such an instance. That's at the very core of what "object-oriented" is all about.

In your case, `A` is abstract and can't have direct instances. So the only way to call your method is to have some instance of some class `B` that extends `A`. You can either find an existing subclass that you can use, or create your own subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract Class:

```
    package com.test;
    public abstract class MyAbstract {

      public abstract void abstractMethod();

      public void callNonAbstractMethod() {


        System.out.println("Hello");
      }
    }
```

The anonymous class:

```
 package com.test;

    public class Example {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example().something();
      }

      void something() {
        MyAbstract a = new MyAbstract() {

          @Override
          public void abstractMethod() {
            //TODO implement
          }
        };
        a.callNonAbstractMethod();
      }
    }
```

Internal class generated by the compiler would be for above example.

```
static class Example  extends MyAbstract 
        {  
           Example(){}
           void abstractMethod()  
            {  
                System.out.println("hiee");  
            }  
        }
```

Abstract Class:

```
  package com.test;
    public abstract class MyAbstract {

      public abstract void abstractMethod();

      public void callNonAbstractMethod() {


        System.out.println("Hello");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use an anonymous class. Although it is a kind of extension, you are not explicitly using the keyword extends. In fact, you cannot use any class in java without implicitly extending because every class extends `Object`.

```
package com.test;

public class Example {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Example().something();
  }

  void something() {
    MyAbstract a = new MyAbstract() {

      @Override
      public void abstractMethod() {
        //TODO implement
      }
    };
    a.callNonAbstractMethod();
  }
}
```

and here's your abstract class:

```
package com.test;

public abstract class MyAbstract {

  public abstract void abstractMethod();

  public void callNonAbstractMethod() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}
```

results in:

`Hello`

Comment: I downvoted because you extend `MyAbstract`, just with a different syntax.

Comment: Yes, but I think the author of the question meant not using the keyword `extends`

Comment: Although that's not completely impossible, my understanding is that the OP struggles with basic concepts of OOP.